# Gradle - finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, gradle

My gradle build showed this error, any idea?

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:shownail_android:ShowNail:assembleShownailtestDebug, :RongIMKit:assembleDebug]
Information:Kotlin: Kotlin JPS plugin is disabled
Information:15/11/24 上午10:57 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 39s 500ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':shownail_android:ShowNail:dexShownailtestDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as easy as you can see. There are some java compile errors out there in your code.

build your project with the same tasks and append option **'--stacktrace'**, see what's going wrong.